# What are the best practices for persisting the customer address(es) at checkout?

Tags: checkout, cart

I'm working on a flow that would allow for a one page checkout for one of my clients and we might consider a plugin but there's a requirement to persist the addresses(shipping/billing) when the logged-in customer reaches a certain step at checkout, abandons and returns to complete the checkout. Is it a good practice to persist the addresses for these scenario so that the customer doesn't have to go through the trouble of re-entering all of their addresses or should the returning customer re-enter that information?

Will appreciate your help with this and perhaps point me to a post that provides details around best practices.

Thanks

Comment: How about store it in a cookie with JS and fill the inputs when the page loads?

Comment: Thanks mbalparda. That sounds like a great idea. I did hear that the client wants to store cart information (such as cart ID and qty, customer ID, etc in a database) and have a cookie pull that information from there. Will storing the addresses in a cookie cause any issues with that requirement? Also, do you think it is a good practice to actually persist the addresses when the user abandons the checkout without completing it? From a user experience perspective it sounds like a great idea but I want to find out if that would be a good practice in general.

Comment: If you name the cookie with a different name you should not have an issue. From the best practice side, i think its doable and a good approach. I will add this as an answer for the record.

Comment: Ok cool. Thank you. I'll continue researching online if there's additional details around it. In the meantime, will pass this on to the developers and the business owner. So from your perspective this second cookie would load when the returning logged-in user arrives on the checkout page, correct?

Comment: Yes, it can be made observing the load of the checkout step you want to fill with info from the cookie.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so  much for your help. If I find any other supporting information, I'll post it here as well. Cheers!

Comment: Cool. Remember to mark the question as resolved once it actually is.

Comment: Could I hold off until I have shared and confirmed with the developers and the business owner? I want to make sure I keep this open if they come back with more questions. LMK

Comment: Of course, it was just a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You can store this in a cookie with JS and load it when the page loads and fill the inputs with the stored info.

You will have to put a disclamer to say your site uses cookies, but beyond that its pretty easy to achieve.